# SQL Server does not exist or access denied - for SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, iis, error-handling, asp-classic, sql-server-express

I have a local SQL Server 2017 Express database which I can connect to from a C# console app with the connection string

```
SERVER=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;DATABASE=brain;uid=brain;pwd=xxxxxx
```

It works fine from the .NET app.

However I wanted to quickly knock up an ASP classic page so I could see some of the data from a browser and it doesn't work using that connection string.

I tried changing the server to what

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

returned which was HP\LOCALDB#0B1B079F

However that didn't work either.

I looked at some other answers which were to add a pass in the firewall and I did that even though the SQL Server and app/web page are on the same machine, my laptop. However that did nothing either.

I am just wondering why the C# App works but the ASP page doesn't. The rest of the ASP executes just not the connection to the DB.

The ASP code is just

```
Set objCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objCon.open "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;DATABASE=brain;uid=brain;pwd=xxxxxx;"
objCon.CommandTimeout = 0
Set objRS = objCon.Execute(strSQL)
```

It fails on the `objCon.open` line.

Just not sure why a command prompt running a console app (for the moment until its made into an APP), works but IIS ASP Classic using the same connection string doesn't.

Comment: Your .NET connection string uses the [format for the native client](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/). `SQLOLEDB` is a [different provider](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/).

Comment: So which provider should I use, I just copied down the connection string from the ASP page on the server which worked with SQL Server 2012, and that ASP classic connection also used that provider objCon.open "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB; SERVER=LOCALHOST; DATABASE=brain; uid=brain; pwd=xxxxx;" - so on the main server the ASP page worked with that provider. So did the c# app. Just on local laptop only the c# app works with that connection string NOT the ASP page. So the difference is the type of SQL Server e.g Express, so which provider should I now use for ASP classic -> SQL Express 2017?

Comment: No, the difference is that SqlConnection uses the native client and hence a connection string in the format for the native client, and for ASP you have declared sqloledb which requires a different format. If you want to copy connection strings in this manner then declare the native client as the provider in the ASP connection string.

Comment: Look up the correct connection string for `SQLOLEDB` on [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/) but remember that the `SQLOLEDB` provider was only supported up until SQL Server 2000. You should be using other providers for newer SQL Server versions be it ODBC or OLEDB.

Answer (score 1):

We can take advantage of the SQL Server Object Explorer in VS to obtain the connection string. It should be in line with the norms. After we added the SQL Server by using Add Server wizard, we can check the connect string property of the SQL Server.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Under this circumstance, the ADO.Net library and Entity Framework can connect to the SQL Server properly on my side.
Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks I will try that out, I never normally use VS for DB work, usually create the DB separately then connect to it with the app but I will try this as it seem a logical way to get the right connection string. The SQLOLEDB provider was given to me by a previous answer when we moved from 32bit to 64bit servers and there were a lot of changes I had to make to existing stored procs as debug in procs came b4 the result, causing recordset parsing errors, set nocount on was a must for all procs plus more tweaks. I didn't realise SQLOLEDB was such an old provider when it is given to me as default

Comment: The connection string I get, is the same as yours for SQL Express e.g (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB which is the same as the SERVER / Data Source I use in my C# console app connection string which works, and when I connect MS Management Console to the DB, its that connection string as well. I just don't get why I have a different value for select @@servername which returns HP\LOCALDB#88CF18DC -something I have never seen or use either in C# app or MS Console. I have tried using that value but it doesn't work. The connection in my C# app uses the same server name as MS Console to connect to the DB